# Elastic goes down

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have ELK stack with Redis.
Scheme is: logstash -> redis -> logstash(indexer) -> elasticsearch -> kibana

Logstash indexer get data from Redis and put it to elastic:

```
    input { 
                redis { 
                        host=>"redis"
                        type=>"redis-input"
                        data_type=>"list"
                        key=>"logstash"
                        } 
                }
        filter { 
                geoip { 
                        source=>"ipaddr"
                        target=>"geoip"
                        database=>"/GeoLiteCity.dat"
                        add_field=>["[geoip][coordinates]","%{[geoip][longitude]}"]
                        add_field=>["[geoip][coordinates]","%{[geoip][latitude]}"]
                        } 
                mutate {
                        remove_field=>["message","@version","timestamp"]
                        convert=>{"[geoip][coordinates]"=>"float"}
                        }
                }
        output { 
                    elasticsearch { 
                                    template=>"/typing-template.json"
                                    template_overwrite=>true
                                    hosts=>["elasticsearch:9200"] 
                                    }
                }
```

There is 4 server which logs I want to collect. Here is their logstash conf:

```
input {
    file {
        path => [ "C:/Program Files (x86)/*/logs/*.log", "C:/Program Files (x86)/**/logs/*.log", "C:/Program Files/***/logs/*.log", "C:/Program Files/****/logs/*.log" ]
        start_position => "beginning"
        type => "mtdclog"
        ignore_older => 0
        sincedb_path => "NUL"
            }
}   

filter {
        grok {      match => { "path" => "%{GREEDYDATA}/(?<logdate>[0-9]{8})\.log" }}
        grok {      match => [  "message", "%{NONNEGINT:log_stream}\t%{TIME:logtime}\s{1,2}%{IPV4:ipaddr}\t'%{NUMBER:account}': (?<event>login) \[ver: (?<client_build>[0-9\.]+)",
                                "message", "%{NONNEGINT:log_stream}\t%{TIME:logtime}\s{1,2}%{IPV4:ipaddr}\t'%{NUMBER:account}': (?<event>liveupdate) '%{GREEDYDATA:data}'",
                                "message", "%{NONNEGINT:log_stream}\t%{TIME:logtime}\s{1,2}%{IPV4:ipaddr}\t'%{NUMBER:account}': (?<event>check version)%{GREEDYDATA:data}",
                                "message", "%{NONNEGINT:log_stream}\t%{TIME:logtime}\s{1,2}%{IPV4:ipaddr}\t'%{NUMBER:account}': %{GREEDYDATA:data}",
                                "message", "%{NONNEGINT:log_stream}\t%{TIME:logtime}\s{1,2}(?<event>News):%{GREEDYDATA:data}",
                                "message", "%{NONNEGINT:log_stream}\t%{TIME:logtime}\s{1,2}%{IPV4:ipaddr}\t(?<event>unknown command) (?<command_code>[A-Z0-9]+)",
                                "message", "%{NONNEGINT:log_stream}\t%{TIME:logtime}\s{1,2}(?<event>History):%{GREEDYDATA:data}",
                                "message", "%{NONNEGINT:log_stream}\t%{TIME:logtime}\s{1,2}%{GREEDYDATA:log_line}",
                                "message", "%{GREEDYDATA:log_line}"
                                ]   
                    }

        mutate {
            add_field => { "ts" => "%{logdate} %{logtime}"} 
            remove_field => [ "logdate", "logtime" ]
                }

        date {
                match => [ "ts", "YYYYMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
                target => "@timestamp"
                }   


        if [path] =~ "Pattern1" { mutate {  add_field => { "dc_type" => "Pattern1" }    }}
        if [path] =~ "Pattern2" { mutate {  add_field => { "dc_type" => "Pattern2" }    }}

        mutate {    remove_field => [ "message", "@version", "ts", "path", "host"  ]    
                    add_field => { "location" => "somecity" }
                    convert => {    "log_stream" => "integer"
                                    "client_build"   => "integer"
                                    "account" => "integer"
                                    }
                    }                               

}

output {

            redis  {
            host => "xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa"
            port => "6381"
            data_type => "list"
            key => "logstash" }
```

Task:
I want to process old logs for 1 month period. It is about 35MB of daily log files. So total amount from 4 servers is about 140MB, not so much.

Problem:
Then I start logstash services - all is good and works fine for 4-5 hours. I see parsed data in kibana and can work with it. But then elastic goes down.
Message is "Request Timeout after 30000ms".

Same ELK stack I'm using for another servers and logstash configs - it works greate and process more log lines. But I can't understand the trouble in this case.

Answer (score 0):

also I've implemented mappings for logstash indexer:

```
{
  "template" : "logstash-*",
  "settings" : {
    "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
      "_all" : {"enabled" : true, "omit_norms" : true},
      "dynamic_templates" : [ {
        "message_field" : {
          "match" : "message",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
            "fielddata" : { "format" : "disabled" }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "string_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
            "fielddata" : { "format" : "disabled" },
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "doc_values" : true, "ignore_above" : 256}
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "float_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "float",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "float", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "double_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "double",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "double", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "byte_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "byte",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "byte", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "short_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "short",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "short", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "integer_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "integer",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "integer", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "long_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "long",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "long", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "date_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "date",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "date", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "geo_point_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "geo_point",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "geo_point", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      } ],
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp": { "type": "date", "doc_values" : true },
        "@version": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed", "doc_values" : true },
        "ipaddr": { "type": "ip", "doc_values" : true },
        "ping": {"type": "float", "doc_values" : true },
        "geoip"  : {
          "type" : "object",
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties" : {
            "ip": { "type": "ip", "doc_values" : true },
            "location" : { "type" : "geo_point", "doc_values" : true },
            "latitude" : { "type" : "float", "doc_values" : true },
            "longitude" : { "type" : "float", "doc_values" : true }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```